# Group then in table is unique id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table like this:

`+---------------------+-------------+-----------------------------------+
| ID| Subject| Message | Create date | Message_U_ID                      |
+----------------------+-------------+-----------------------------------+
| 1 | TEST1  | text1   | 2014-10-01..| 8f918db316f64c638b7b6d1fcd3c0ea3  |
| 2 | TEST1  | text1   | 2014-10-01..| 8f918db316f64c638b7b6d1fcd3c0ea3  |
| 3 | TEST1  | text1   | 2014-10-01..| 8f918db316f64c638b7b6d1fcd3c0ea3  |
| 4 | TEST2  | text2   | 2014-10-02..| cb648984779b4af9bc04d9de7fc5939b  |
| 5 | TEST2  | text2   | 2014-10-02..| cb648984779b4af9bc04d9de7fc5939b  |
| 6 | TEST3  | text3   | 2014-10-03..| bb43ea1de81340bb95320217dcd6363b  |
+------------+---------+-------------+-----------------------------------+`

ID is unique message ID. Message_U_ID is unique id who generate then I send  message to group (Active directory). I want get Subject and Message (only first for every Message_U_ID). Result should be like this:

`+---------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| Subject| Message | Message_U_ID                      |
+----------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| TEST1  | text1   | 8f918db316f64c638b7b6d1fcd3c0ea3  |
| TEST2  | text2   | cb648984779b4af9bc04d9de7fc5939b  |
| TEST3  | text3   | bb43ea1de81340bb95320217dcd6363b  |
+------------+---------+-------------+-----------------+`

I try GROUO BY and DISTINCT, but I cant get good result.

Comment: The first would naturally be the one with the lowest create date, but it looks like the create date is the same for all records with the same Message_U_ID? If so, what would you consider to be the first record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this in SQL Server is using `row_number()`:

```
selet t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by message_u_id order by create_date) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```